# Is it ok to run a 100 amp sub panel off a 150 amp main panel?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, subpanel

I'm installing a GE 100 Amp MLO panel about 50 feet from the main panel in a different building that's about 700 sq/ft.

I'm pulling three #3 in 1-1/4" PVC with a #6 ground. The main is a 150 running a three bedroom house (40amp range, 40 gal electric water heater, mini-split AC) and also has a 60 amp double pole breaker for a subpanel in a shop.

My question is would this be permitted or do I need to upgrade the main panel.

Comment: What make and model is your new panel? (We'll probably have to convert it to main breaker to provide a building shutoff means for the new building.)  Also: can you provide us with the square footage of the house, whether the major appliances (stove/range, furnace, water heater, and dryer) are gas or electric, and the nameplate data off your air conditioner is (presuming you have one of course)? We need that for load calculation purposes...

Comment: Last but not least: do you already have the wire and conduit installed, or would you be open to other ideas on that front? And does your jurisdiction ban aluminum wire, or is there some other reason you're using copper for such a fat feeder?

Comment: Its a ge 125 mlo panel.the new space is about 700 sq feet if even and has a 40 amp range plug a 40 gal water heater and a split ac unit ..the wire and condui is not installed

Comment: Is the new space intended to be an accessory dwelling unit (in-law suite, ADU)?  What size is the existing house, and is that 40 gal water heater gas or electric?  How are both the new space and the existing house heated?

Comment: Yes its a in law suite.the existing house is 3 bedroom and the water heater is electric.the new addition doesnt have a heating plan yet but the house is on gas

Comment: @DevonSwartz please [edit] answers to future questions into your post. Not everyone will read and find all the answers down here in the comments, plus comments may get deleted in the future, meaning they'd be lost.

Comment: @DevonSwartz -- we need the *square footage* of the existing house, the # of bedrooms doesn't even figure into the calculations we'll be doing here.  Also: can you post photos of your existing circuit breaker panel please?

Comment: Note that the amperage of the main breaker does not limit the number of "sub" breakers (or panels) that can be installed. It's a limit on the _total, simultaneous_ load that the breaker will support. If you're currently using 150A of power in your main panel, turning _anything_ on from the subpanel will likely trip it the main. However, the odds of you _ever_ using 150a at your main are slim, as are the odds of using 100a at the sub. You _could_ put a 200a sub panel in the garage, doesn't mean you're going to draw all that power at any one time.

Comment: Actually, you should use a 200A panel.  A 100A panel *has too few spaces* and you'll run out.  Spaces are dirt cheap, running out of spaces is expensive.  Scrimping on the panel is a false economy.  Size of the subpanel does not matter... well, put it this way, if you drive a lot in Wyoming with 80 mph speed limits, would you rather have 85 mph tires, or 130 mph tires?

Comment: Also in the "spending your money" department, pull #1 aluminum not #3 copper. Same job, 1/3 the price.  If you've heard scary stories about aluminum, they don't apply to large feeder like this - heck, the lugs are aluminum, so using copper *creates* a dissimilar-metal problem...